# $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{x^2}$ without L'Hôpital

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Can someone help me to find the following limit without using L'Hôpital ?
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 9):

*Hint:* $$e^{2x} = 1 + 2x + \dfrac{(2x)^2}{2!} + o(x^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the use of the Taylor series or the Lagrange/Cauchy theorem, too, you can go back to the definition of the exponential function and recall that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, with
$$ a_n = \left(1+\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n $$
is an increasing sequence (slowly) converging towards $e^{2x}$. So by taking $x$ sufficiently close to zero ($|x|<1$) and $n$ sufficiently big ($n\geq 3$), in virtue of the binomial theorem, one has:
$$ e^{2x}-1-2x = \sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(2x)^k}{n^k} = 2\frac{n-1}{n}x^2+\sum_{k=3}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(2x)^k}{n^k},$$
and:
$$\left|\sum_{k=3}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(2x)^k}{n^k}\right|\leq\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{(2|x|)^k}{k!}\leq (e^2-5)|x|^3\leq\frac{5}{2}|x|^3,$$
so the limit is clearly $2$.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
this is my try for help you to find the following limit without using L'Hôpital

Comment: There is a slight issue here. Your method assumes that limit $l$ in your figure above exists. You can't assume this without any sufficient justification. By the way I have not downvoted your answer because it represents a good approach accessible to beginners. Also please try to use $\mathrm\LaTeX$ instead of using a picture.